# the plot showing one color for all the graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

i tried to get many graphs in one plot in different colors but only one color shown in all the graphs, and all the graphs return to 0 at the last value except the last graph, and I also tried to make the color attribute for example `plt.plot(x,y,color='r')` but same output
this is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m


data_t = []
data=[]
data_v = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
l=[(0,0.016699),(1,0.023958),(2,0.02724),(3,0.033468),(4,0.42456),(5,0.059325),(6,0.063399),(7,0.079788),(8,0.095916),(9,0.125),(10,0.14622),(11,0.20257),(12,0.21643),(13,0.28974),(14,0.4424),(15,0.55856),(16,0.59991),(17,0.72561),(18,0.9964),(19,1.6748),(20,1.69)]

for x in range(len(l)):
    a=l[x][0]
    c=l[x][1]
    for i in range (3600):
        t=i
        v=m.sqrt((2*(150-(40*9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))))/(1.2*c*0.875))*m.tanh(m.sqrt(((150/40)-9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))*(1.2*c*0.875*0.0125))*t)
        data_t.append(t)
        data.append(v)
        data_v[x]=data
for i in range(21):
    plt.plot(data_t,data_v[i],label='valeur de alfa'+str(i))

plt.legend(loc='center left',fontsize = 7)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("temps s")
plt.ylabel("vitesse m/s")
plt.title("vitesse en fonction d'angle")
plt.show()
```

this is the graph :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1v3g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not resetting `data_t` and `data` in the loop, at the end, you are plotting one super graph and it is the same for all of them. So the first channel is on top of the rest that you are not seeing them.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

data_v = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

l=[(0,0.016699),(1,0.023958),(2,0.02724),(3,0.033468),(4,0.42456),(5,0.059325),(6,0.063399),(7,0.079788),(8,0.095916),(9,0.125),(10,0.14622),(11,0.20257),(12,0.21643),(13,0.28974),(14,0.4424),(15,0.55856),(16,0.59991),(17,0.72561),(18,0.9964),(19,1.6748),(20,1.69)]

for x in range(len(l)):
    data_t = []
    data = []

    a=l[x][0]
    c=l[x][1]
    for i in range (3600):
        t=i
        v=m.sqrt((2*(150-(40*9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))))/(1.2*c*0.875))*m.tanh(m.sqrt(((150/40)-9.8*m.sin(m.radians(a)))*(1.2*c*0.875*0.0125))*t)
        data_t.append(t)
        data.append(v)
        
    data_v[x]=data
        
for i in range(21):
    plt.plot(data_t,data_v[i],label='valeur de alfa'+str(i))

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("temps s")
plt.ylabel("vitesse m/s")
plt.title("vitesse en fonction d'angle")
plt.legend(loc='center right',fontsize = 7)
plt.show()
```

[image: plots]